# Infinite redirect loop with Gorilla toolkit

Tags: go, gorilla

I have this simple code:

```
import (
   "log"
   "github.com/gorilla/http"
   "bytes"
)

func main() {
 url := "https://www.telegram.org"
 log.Println("url: " + url)
 var b bytes.Buffer
 http.Get(&b, url)
 log.Println("Get done")
}
```

and it freezes on the line making the GET request. It seems that it enters an infinite loop of 302 responses which redirects to the same url ("https://www.telegram.org").
Am I doing or assuming something wrong?

Thanks and regards.

Comment: As the readme states, [the package is still under construction](https://github.com/gorilla/http#image-of-an-under-construction-gif). I suggest using the net/http package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently that library doesn't support https (lol)

https://github.com/gorilla/http/issues/8

So just use the stdlib http module:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {

    res, err := http.Get("https://www.telegram.org")
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    defer res.Body.Close()

    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    fmt.Printf("%s", body)

}
```